# Python Tkinter destroying all Buttons next to chosen one with same text

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, minesweeper

I'm tying to recreate Minesweeper in python and i'm trying to recreate how in the game if the player chooses a tile without anything on it (In my code, a tile that has a 0) it will reveal all the tiles close to it that aren't mines (In my code, a tile that has an X). I've tried to to do this many times but nothing has worked. It would be written in the autoShow(i, j) function.

Can anyone help (Any other suggestions would be appreciated)?

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
from random import randint

def difficulty(diff):
    global rows, cols, mines, size
    if diff == 1:
        rows = 9
        cols = 9
        mines = 10
        size = "341x368"
    elif diff == 2:
        rows = 16
        cols = 16
        mines = 40
        size = "606x654"
    else:
        rows = 16
        cols = 30
        mines = 99
        size = "1139x606"
    play()

def firstT(l, m):
    global firstTurn
    if firstTurn:
        mPos = []
        firstTurn = False
        for x in range(mines):
            minesLoop = True
            while minesLoop:
                x = randint(0, rows - 1)
                y = randint(0, cols - 1)
                if grid_text[x][y].get() != "X":
                    near = False
                    if near == False:
                        mPos.append([x, y])
                        minesLoop = False
                        grid_text[x][y].set("X")
        [[labels[i][j].configure(text = grid_text[i][j].get()) for j in range(cols)] for i in range(rows)]
        for i in range(rows):
            for j in range(cols):
                nearby = 0
                for ii in range(i - 1, i + 2):
                    for jj in range(j - 1, j + 2):
                        if ii >= 0 and jj >= 0 and ii < rows and jj < cols:
                            if labels[i][j]["text"] == "" and labels[ii][jj]["text"] == "X" and not (i, j) in mPos:
                                nearby += 1
                if labels[i][j]["text"] != "X":
                    grid_text[i][j] = str(nearby)
                    labels[i][j].configure(text = grid_text[i][j])

def autoShow(i, j):
    pass

def show(i, j):
    global gameOver
    if gameOver:
        return
    firstT(i, j)
    if labels[i][j]["text"] == "0":
        autoShow(i, j)
    elif labels[i][j]["text"] == "X":
        messagebox.showinfo("Lose!", "You Lose")
        game.focus_force()
        gameOver = True
    else:
        grid[i][j].destroy()

def play():
    global firstTurn, gameOver, game, grid, grid_text, labels
    firstTurn = True
    gameOver = False
    game = tk.Toplevel(root)
    game.title("Minesweeper")
    game.geometry(size)
    grid_text = [[tk.StringVar() for j in range(cols)] for i in range(rows)]
    labels = [[tk.Label(game, text = grid_text[i][j].get()) for j in range(cols)] for i in range(rows)]
    [[labels[i][j].grid(row = i, column = j) for j in range(cols)] for i in range(rows)]
    grid = [[tk.Button(game, width = 4, height = 2, command = lambda i = i, j = j: show(i, j)) for j in range(cols)] for i in range(rows)]
    [[grid[i][j].grid(row = i, column = j) for j in range(cols)] for i in range(rows)]
    xoutside = [[tk.Button(game, width = 4, height = 2).grid(row = i, column = cols + 1) for j in range(cols)] for i in range(rows)]
    youtside = [[tk.Button(game, width = 4, height = 2).grid(row = rows + 1, column = j) for j in range(cols)] for i in range(rows)]

diff(1)
```

Comment: What specifically is the problem? Do you need help getting what's on a label? Do you need help in changing what's on a label? Something else?

Comment: basically i want to destroy buttons if u click an empty space like what happens in minesweeper (look at what happens on your first click on minesweeper: http://minesweeperonline.com/)

Comment: you have `grid` with all buttons and button get `i,j` so use recursion to check neighborhood buttons - `i+1,j`, `i-1,j`, `i.j+1`, `i,j-1`, etc. if it has `0` then show it and use it in recursion, if other numer then only show it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use recursion to run `show(i-1, j)`, etc.

Because I run `show(i-1, j)` without clicking button so I need also `grid[i][j] = None` to recognize if button still exists.

I don't know if it doesn't need other tests in which place is shown.

```
def autoShow(i, j):

    grid[i][j].destroy()
    grid[i][j] = None

    if i > 0:        
        show(i-1, j)
    if j > 0:        
        show(i, j-1)

    if i < rows-1:
        show(i+1, j)
    if j < cols-1:
        show(i, j+1)

    if i > 0 and j > 0:        
        show(i-1, j-1)
    if i > 0 and j < cols-1:        
        show(i-1, j+1)

    if i < rows-1 and j < cols-1:        
        show(i+1, j+1)

    if i < rows-1 and j > 0:        
        show(i+1, j-1)

def show(i, j):
    global gameOver

    if gameOver:
        return

    firstT(i, j)

    # check if button still exists    
    if grid[i][j] is None:
        return

    if labels[i][j]["text"] == "0":
        autoShow(i, j)

    elif labels[i][j]["text"] == "X":
        grid[i][j].destroy()
        grid[i][j] = None
        messagebox.showinfo("Lose!", "You Lose")
        game.focus_force()
        gameOver = True
    else:
        grid[i][j].destroy()
        grid[i][j] = None
```

---

Full code which I tested

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
from random import randint

def difficulty(diff):
    global rows, cols, mines, size
    if diff == 1:
        rows = 9
        cols = 9
        mines = 10
        size = "341x368"
    elif diff == 2:
        rows = 16
        cols = 16
        mines = 40
        size = "606x654"
    else:
        rows = 16
        cols = 30
        mines = 99
        size = "1139x606"
    play()

def firstT(l, m):
    global firstTurn
    if firstTurn:
        mPos = []
        firstTurn = False
        for x in range(mines):
            minesLoop = True
            while minesLoop:
                x = randint(0, rows - 1)
                y = randint(0, cols - 1)
                if grid_text[x][y].get() != "X":
                    near = False
                    if near == False:
                        mPos.append([x, y])
                        minesLoop = False
                        grid_text[x][y].set("X")
        [[labels[i][j].configure(text = grid_text[i][j].get()) for j in range(cols)] for i in range(rows)]
        for i in range(rows):
            for j in range(cols):
                nearby = 0
                for ii in range(i - 1, i + 2):
                    for jj in range(j - 1, j + 2):
                        if ii >= 0 and jj >= 0 and ii < rows and jj < cols:
                            if labels[i][j]["text"] == "" and labels[ii][jj]["text"] == "X" and not (i, j) in mPos:
                                nearby += 1
                if labels[i][j]["text"] != "X":
                    grid_text[i][j] = str(nearby)
                    labels[i][j].configure(text = grid_text[i][j])

def autoShow(i, j):

    grid[i][j].destroy()
    grid[i][j] = None

    if i > 0:        
        show(i-1, j)
    if j > 0:        
        show(i, j-1)

    if i < rows-1:
        show(i+1, j)
    if j < cols-1:
        show(i, j+1)

    if i > 0 and j > 0:        
        show(i-1, j-1)
    if i > 0 and j < cols-1:        
        show(i-1, j+1)

    if i < rows-1 and j < cols-1:        
        show(i+1, j+1)

    if i < rows-1 and j > 0:        
        show(i+1, j-1)

def show(i, j):
    global gameOver
    if gameOver:
        return
    firstT(i, j)

    if grid[i][j] is None:
        return

    if labels[i][j]["text"] == "0":
        autoShow(i, j)

    elif labels[i][j]["text"] == "X":
        grid[i][j].destroy()
        grid[i][j] = None
        messagebox.showinfo("Lose!", "You Lose")
        game.focus_force()
        gameOver = True
    else:
        grid[i][j].destroy()
        grid[i][j] = None

def play():
    global firstTurn, gameOver, game, grid, grid_text, labels
    firstTurn = True
    gameOver = False
    game = tk.Toplevel(root)
    game.title("Minesweeper")
    game.geometry(size)
    grid_text = [[tk.StringVar() for j in range(cols)] for i in range(rows)]
    labels = [[tk.Label(game, text = grid_text[i][j].get()) for j in range(cols)] for i in range(rows)]
    [[labels[i][j].grid(row = i, column = j) for j in range(cols)] for i in range(rows)]
    grid = [[tk.Button(game, width = 4, height = 2, command = lambda i = i, j = j: show(i, j)) for j in range(cols)] for i in range(rows)]
    [[grid[i][j].grid(row = i, column = j) for j in range(cols)] for i in range(rows)]
    xoutside = [[tk.Button(game, width = 4, height = 2).grid(row = i, column = cols + 1) for j in range(cols)] for i in range(rows)]
    youtside = [[tk.Button(game, width = 4, height = 2).grid(row = rows + 1, column = j) for j in range(cols)] for i in range(rows)]

root = tk.Tk()
difficulty(1)
root.mainloop()
```